# Application name issues when publishing mulitple ClickOnce applications with MSBuild

Tags: xslt, msbuild, clickonce

I have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application that has a couple of "modes" to it. I've created an MSBuild script that use [XSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL) transforms on the `.csproj` file (C#/Visual Studio project file) and the `app.config` file to set the configuration parameters for the different environments that the application will be deployed to.

The steps in the script are to build all of the [Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office) versions of the software, of which there are three, transforming the `app.config` and `.csproj` file for each. After which it will do the same for the Truck version of the software and publish those. This is all published to a local folder and then zipped into a [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file which we send to the client.

I've got all of this working, but the issue I'm having now is the *Application Name* inside of the .application files is somehow being cached by the publish process. So that all of the "truck" versions say Mobile on the `publish.htm` page, but when we click on the install link it says *Office* version on the install dialog that pops up.

When I examine the Truck version `.application` files in a text editor I see the following deployment tags:

```
<description co.v1:suiteName="Prover"
             asmv2:product="Prover Office"
             xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
```

Which points to the possibility that the publish operation is somehow caching my product name rather than changing it correctly.

I have tried changing the order of the publish operations to publish the Truck version first and in that case the Product tag will say Prover Truck on all of the Office versions.

I have tired putting in a RemoveDir command to purge the /bin folders inside of the project before each publish to ensure that nothing is getting cached that way. But that did not solve the issue.

The targets that are being called look like this:

```
<Target Name="EnbridgeOfficeDevPublish"
        AfterTargets="JDPOfficePublish"
        DependsOnTargets="CreatePublishDir;">

    <RemoveDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\Bin"/>

    <!--Transform .csproj file-->
    <XslTransformation
        XslInputPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Deployment\OfficeCSProj.xslt"
        XmlInputPaths="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\EBPMND_Prover.csproj"
        OutputPaths="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\EBPMND_Prover.transformed"
        Parameters="&lt;Parameter Name='ApplicationVersion' Value='$(Version)'/&gt;"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\EBPMND_Prover.transformed"
                DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\EBPMND_Prover.csproj"
                OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
    <Delete Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\EBPMND_Prover.transformed"/>

    <!--Transform app.config-->
    <XslTransformation
        XslInputPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Deployment\OfficeDevAppConfig.xslt"
        XmlInputPaths="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\app.config"
        OutputPaths="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\app.config.transformed"/>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\app.config.transformed"
        DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\app.config"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
    <Delete Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\EBPMND_Prover\app.config.transformed"/>

    <MSBuild
        Projects="EBPMND_Prover\EBPMND_Prover.csproj"
        Properties="Configuration=Release;InstallUrl=http://houvwebd/Prover/;PublishDir=$(PublishDir)\OfficeDev\;ApplicationVersion=$(Version)"
        Targets="Publish"/>
    <Message Text="------Dev Office Publish Completed-----"/>
</Target>
```

And the XSL files are pretty straightforward. Here's an example of the `.csproj` XSL file.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build:PropertyGroup/build:ProductName">
    <ProductName>Prover Truck</ProductName>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build:PropertyGroup/build:InstallUrl">
    <InstallUrl>http://houvwebd/Prover/Truck/</InstallUrl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build:PropertyGroup/build:PublishUrl">
    <PublishUrl>D:\Projects\PrecompiledWeb\Prover\Truck\</PublishUrl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build:PropertyGroup/build:CreateDesktopShortcut">
    <CreateDesktopShortcut>true</CreateDesktopShortcut>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build:ApplicationVersion">
    <ApplicationVersion>
        <xsl:value-of select="$ApplicationVersion"/>
    </ApplicationVersion>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build:PropertyGroup/build:Install">
    <Install>True</Install>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build:SignManifests">
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
</xsl:template>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I ended up making multiple msbuild files and have our integration server build them independently of each other when a new version is committed to VCS. I still haven't figured out where or why these settings are caching but at least I have a solution for now.